# Can I manipulate when DisplayObjects will render in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, rendering

Without using `BitmapData.draw()`; is it possible to stop the display list from rendering, and perform a render when I see fit (whether that is of the entire display list or individual DisplayObjects).

If not, what is the best method to achieve this (inclusive of the option where I use `BitmapData.draw()` to render DisplayObjects that haven't been added to the stage)?

Comment: i think changing container creation policy can also help to some extent.. depending what exactly you wan to achieve

Comment: Isn't that what the timeline is for? Put the objects at the temporal point when you want them to appear/render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a render after a mouse/keyboard event using [`e.updateAfterEvent()`](http://drkgodz.hobo-studios.org/blog/?p=132), but you cannot prevent the display list from redrawing to screen. Your best bet would be :

1. Add all your objects into one `holder` Sprite, which is off the stage display list.
2. Add a `Bitmap` and associated `BitmapData` to the stage.
3. Everytime you want to 'force' a render simply `draw()` the `holder` onto the `BitmapData` and it will be rasterized by the exact same renderer that typically operates. Just that you get more control over the rasterizing settings.

Try the following, or see [this](http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/bddraw/) for more info:

```
function snapClip( clip:DisplayObject ):BitmapData
{
   var bounds:Rectangle = clip.getBounds( clip );
   var bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData( int( bounds.width + 0.5 ), int( bounds.height + 0.5 ), true, 0 );
   bitmap.draw( clip, new Matrix(1,0,0,1,-bounds.x,-bounds.y) );
   return bitmap;
}
```